# How to launch and close every browser after every @Test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to launch and close my browser after every @Test but I am unable to is the only solution to create a new function .java and add my second @Test in it or can i do it in the same .java .

I searched a little bit but I keep finding @beforetest and @aftertest but those two only are executed once i want them to execute for every @test.

Example of my code :

```
@BeforeTest
public void LaunchBrowser() throws IOException {
    // Where I have my launch code
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void Commande_Simple_Mode_Connecte() throws InterruptedException {
    Authentication(driver);
    RechercheMarque(driver, "adidas");
    SaisieArticle(driver);
    AccesPanierSimple(driver);
    ValidationCommandeSimple(driver);
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void Commande_Simple_Etrangere_Mode_Deconnecte() throws InterruptedException {
    RechercheArticleMD(driver,"ocstore");
    SaisieArticleEtrangerMD(driver);
    AccesPanierSimple(driver);
    AuthenticationDepuisPanierDeconnecter(driver);
    ValidationCommandeSimpleEtrangere(driver);
}

@AfterTest
public void CloseChrome() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Which testing framework are you working with? It is not clear from your example.

Comment: I would say none i just have a main class where i put the functions to execute and another .java where i have my functions to execute

Comment: These `@Test` and `@AfterTest` annotations come from _somewhere_. My best guess would be TestNG. But I'd rather not guess.

Comment: Ow my bad then yes i am using testng to execute my code i didnt understand framework from the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using TestNG, I would consult its [documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations), which points out these two annotations:

```
@BeforeMethod: The annotated method will be run before each test method.
@AfterMethod: The annotated method will be run after each test method.
```

It seems these should enable you to run code before or after each test method.